# How to expand PrimeNg TreeTable by code

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-treetable

Assuming I have a TreeTable provided by PrimeNg for Angular2. How can I expand a particular node in code (for example in `onNodeSelect` callback)?

Comment: although is not related to `treetable` could be used as inspiration: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38285593/how-to-initialize-primeng-tree-component/38285594#38285594

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I guess the OP no longer needs the answer, but for anyone who reaches here and finds no answer -

There is a property `expanded` for `TreeNode`, all you need to do is just set it to `true`

```
selectedNode.expanded=true;
```

And if you want the tree to be shown all expanded, just traverse the TreeNodes and set expanded on each.  Which will be something similar to this

```
  expandChildren(node:TreeNode){
    if(node.children){
      node.expanded=true;
      for(let cn of node.children){
        this.expandChildren(cn);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Possible to do the same but make it selected?

Comment: this only change the icon does not expand or collapse the table

Comment: @AhsanSohail The answer is years old, when the angular version was 1.2

Comment: @prajeeshkumar So.. how can i expand tree node in 2019? Would you share a solution please?

Comment: @vladimirkhozeyev Haven't worked in angular for sometime now, will update if I do

Comment: @prajeeshkumar thank you in advance. I found just one solution, and it is out of MVVM concept (find expand button in DOM and emulate mouse click).

Comment: @vladimirkhozeyev i used the same sollution but i added a methode to update visibility, but it dosent seems clean because it refrech th ui     updateVisibility(): void {
        this.visible = false;
        setTimeout(() => (this.visible = true), 0);
    }

Comment: You need to keep the change detection in mind. Due to performance, changes are only detected, when the reference of the value changes. So if you are iterating over your tree and change the expanded attribute of nodes in your tree, you need to update the reference like for example: this.yourTreeTable = [...this.yourTreeTable]. Then your UI will be refreshed. It is here documentated under [Change Detection] (http://primefaces.org/primeng/v9.1.5-lts/#/treetable)

Answer (score 3):

Once the code mentioned by prajeesh kumar is executed, to get the tree table refreshed, please add the following line of code:

```
this.treeNodeData = [...this.treeNodeData];
```

You can call the expandChildren() method like this:

```
  expandTreeNodes() {
    if (this.treeNodeData) {
      this.treeNodeData.forEach(x => this.expandChildren(x));

      // Below line is important as it would refresh the TreeTable data,
      // which would force automatic update of nodes and since expanded
      // has been set to true on the expandChildren() method.

      this.treeNodeData = [...this.treeNodeData ]; 
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using above I just wrote function for expanding/collapsing entire treatable nodes.

In my template I am passing entire treetable json to exapandORcollapse

```
<button type="button" (click)="exapandORcollapse(basicTreeTable)">Collapse /Expand all</button>
 <p-treeTable [value]="basicTreeTable" selectionMode="single" [(selection)]="selectedPortfolio" (onNodeSelect)="nodeSelect($event)"
            (onNodeUnselect)="nodeUnselect($event)" (onRowDblclick)="onRowDblclick($event)" scrollable="true">
```

In my component.ts file

```
 exapandORcollapse(nodes) {
    for(let node of nodes) 
  { 
    if (node.children) {
        if(node.expanded == true)
          node.expanded = false;
          else
          node.expanded = true;
        for (let cn of node.children) {
            this.exapandORcollapse(node.children);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In my case completely  doesn't works, it doesn't show children, only caret change

Comment: its only expanded upto certain levels not deeply expanded or collapsed.

Answer (score 0):

I did the same but I cloned the same tree object to itself and it worked.

```
this.treeData.forEach((node) => {this.expandRecursive(node, true);});
this.treeData = _.cloneDeep(this.treeData);
```