# PrimeNG Treetable programmatically expand all nodes not working

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm trying to recursively expand all nodes on a Primeng TreeTable component but without success.
The row icons change and nothing more happens, except when i manualy click on the expand/colapse icon and all nodes are expanded/collapsed accordingly.

Here a stackbliz link for what i'm trying to do, [Stackblitz code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-treetable-demo-nsvdr8)

And this are my expand/colapse methods:

```
public expandAll(): void {
    this.files1.forEach(node => {
        this.expandCollapseRecursive(node, true);
    });
}

public collapseAll(): void {
    this.files1.forEach(node => {
        this.expandCollapseRecursive(node, false);
    });
}

private expandCollapseRecursive(node: TreeNode, isExpand: boolean): void {
    node.expanded = isExpand;
    if (node.children) {
        node.children.forEach(childNode => {
            this.expandCollapseRecursive(childNode, isExpand);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37616995/how-to-expand-primeng-treetable-by-code?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that works for me using [Lodash](https://lodash.com/) [cloneDeep](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#cloneDeep), making a deep clone from the TreeNode array then doing all the changes in the cloned one before overwriting the "this.files1" property, then everything works.

```
public expandAll(): void {
    const temp = cloneDeep(this.files1);
    temp.forEach(node => {
        this.expandCollapseRecursive(node, true);
    });
    this.files1 = temp;
}

public collapseAll(): void {
    const temp = cloneDeep(this.files1);
    temp.forEach(node => {
        this.expandCollapseRecursive(node, false);
    });
    this.files1 = temp;
}

private expandCollapseRecursive(node: TreeNode, isExpand: boolean): void {
    node.expanded = isExpand;
    if (node.children) {
        node.children.forEach(childNode => {
            this.expandCollapseRecursive(childNode, isExpand);
        });
    }
}
```

But is there a better answer?

Answer (score 0):

I used the following solution, it helps to keep the state of checkboxes by simulating click events on the TreeTableToggler:

```
    private fillExpanded(v: TreeNode[], value: boolean){
        for(let it of v){
            it.expanded = value;
            if(it.children){
                this.fillExpanded(it.children, value);
            }
        }
    }

    private simulateClickOn(query: string){
        let v = this.ref.nativeElement.querySelectorAll(query);
        v.forEach(i=>{
            (i as HTMLElement).click();
        });
    }

    expandAll(){
        for(let x of this.renderData){
            if(x.children){
                this.fillExpanded(x.children, true);
            }
        }
        this.simulateClickOn('i.pi-chevron-right');
    }

    collapseAll(){
        this.simulateClickOn('i.pi-chevron-down');
    }
```